# watchpoint(hardware) in gdb for a variable fails saying 'Suspended (tty output)'

Tags: gdb

When I insert a watchpoint(hardware) in gdb for a variable, as soon the variable value changes, gdb session gets suspended printing 'Suspended (tty output)'. How to get proper output without suspending gdb session? Also tried set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0, still the same error.

Comment: gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC), Target: x86_64-redhat-linux, Thread model: posix, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650

Comment: And what would expected output look like?

Comment: Something like this:
`(gdb) watch x`
`Hardware watchpoint 4: x `
`(gdb) c `
`Continuing. `
`Hardware watchpoint 4: x `
`Old value = -1073743192 `
`New value = 11 `
`main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffaf4) at test.c:10 `
`10 return 0;`

Comment: Ok. The usual watchpoint output. I was wondering about "without suspending gdb session" part. Just given it a try on 64 bit CentOS 6 and as expected I get the usual output (basic testcase). You will probably need to share some code to get useful answer. Also try gdb mailing list.

Comment: While the cause is unclear, [this might be a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056102/why-do-i-get-suspended-tty-output-in-one-terminal-but-not-in-others)