# why do I get "Suspended (tty output)" in one terminal but not in others?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, rhel

Apparently I've done something strange/wrong in a tcsh shell, and now whenever I start an application in the background which prints to stdout the application is suspended (stopped). Weird thing is, this behavior only happens in this terminal; if I do the same in another terminal, the application just keeps running in the background and prints it output to the terminal.

In the "broken" terminal I have to put the suspended application back into foreground (with `fg`) to have it continue.

Example:

```
thehost:/tmp/test1(277)> ls -l &
[3] 1454
thehost:/tmp/test1(278)> 
[3]  + Suspended (tty output)        ls --color=auto -l
thehost:/tmp/test1(278)> fg
ls --color=auto -l
total 0
thehost:/tmp/test1(279)>
```

Same command executed in another terminal works fine:

```
thehost:/tmp/test1(8)> ls -l &                                                 
[1] 2280                                                                        
thehost:/tmp/test1(9)> total 0                                                 

[1]    Done                          ls --color=auto -l                         
thehost:/tmp/test1(9)>
```

Starting a bash in the affected terminal doesn't solve this either:

```
thehost:/tmp/test1(280)> bash
oliver@thehost:/tmp/test1$ ls -l &
[1] 2263
oliver@thehost:/tmp/test1$ 

[1]+  Stopped                 ls --color=auto -l
oliver@thehost:/tmp/test1$ fg
ls --color=auto -l
total 0
oliver@thehost:/tmp/test1$
```

Getting a new login shell (with `su - oliver`) doesn't solve this either.

So: what did I do in this terminal to get this behavior, and **what can I do to get back the normal behavior**? It's not really an important problem (I could close the terminal and open a new one), but I'm curious :-)

Happens on Linux RHEL 6.4 64bit, with KDE 4.11.5 and Konsole 2.11.3, and tcsh 6.17.00.

Comment: Related on [unix.se]: [When I run `./command.sh &` the background task is suspended. How can I keep it running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166477/when-i-run-command-sh-the-background-task-is-suspended-how-can-i-keep-it)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
stty -tostop
```

From the man page:

> tostop (-tostop)
>
> Send (do not send) SIGTTOU for background output.  This causes background jobs to stop if they attempt terminal output.

This `tostop` is normally the default setting, as it's usually undesirable to mix the output of multiple jobs. So most people just want the foreground job to be able to print to the terminal.

Comment: did not fix it for me unfortunately :c Trying to run multiple gradle builds in the background, but they are all suspended

Comment: Could something in the build script be changing the `stty` settings? What does `stty --all` show?

Comment: This: https://pastebin.com/nGzySBS2 I am sure that nothing changes the stty settings in the buildscripts. I use zsh btw. This is the command that starts each build: `(gradle build --no-daemon --console=rich &>"/tmp/build-$(basename $d)") &`

Comment: Maybe zsh manages background processes differently from bash.

Comment: This worked great for solving my issue in zsh.  So it's not just bash related.  My issue was my background jobs were getting suspended but only in one particular zsh session.  Thanks to this answer I now believe some other tool I had previously run in the same session had set `stty tostop`.  Running this returned the behavior to what I'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

For `zsh` you can use:

```
nohup ls -l 2>/dev/null &
```

so `nohup [command] 2>/dev/null &`

Hope that helps

Comment: Just if someone do not know what 2>/dev/null does.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean

Comment: NOTE: You can still use the other answer if you're in `zsh`. Using `nohup` just prevents you background job from outputting which prevents the automatic suspension if `stty tostop` is enabled. But using `nohup` wasn't necessary for me.  Just setting `stty -tostop` as shown in the other answer fixed the issue for me in zsh.