# When I run `ffmpeg` in the background, how do I prevent `suspended (tty output)`?

Tags: ffmpeg, multiprocessing, sh

I have a `sh` script which calls [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) on several files. When I try to run this script in the background, redirecting output to a file, the job starts but then immediately suspends:

```
% bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &> ~/tmp/log.txt &
[1] 93352
% 
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &>
```

If I try making the script continue in the background, it immediately suspends again:

```
% jobs
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &> 
% bg %1
[1]  + continued  bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &> 
% jobs
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &> 
%
```

I can make the script continue, by making it the foreground, but then my terminal is occupied until the script finishes. That means I don't get the benefit of running the script in the background.

```
% 
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &> 
% fg %1
[1]  + continued  bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &> 
% # much time passes with no activity on terminal, then script finishes
%
```

How can I make the script run cleanly in the background?

A simplified version of my script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# mp3convert.sh
for f in "$1"/*.flac; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy path/to/dest/"$(basename -s .flac "$f")".mp3
done
```

I am running on Mac OS X 10.11.6, with [`ffmpeg` version 3.4](http://ffmpeg.org/)  supplied by [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

An apparently related question is [*why do I get “Suspended (tty output)” in one terminal but not in others?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056102/why-do-i-get-suspended-tty-output-in-one-terminal-but-not-in-others). The answer there is to set the terminal state with `stty -tostop`. That didn't help me; I already had that state set.

Comment: Now that I've pressed the Ask button, it occurs to me that this question might fit more appropriately in [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg).

Answer (score 5):

`ffmpeg` enables interaction with **stdin** by default. (See [documentation on its `-stdin` option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options).) On Mac OS X and Linux systems, this causes an `ffmpeg` job running in the background to suspend, though oddly with a message about "tty output" rather than "tty input".

Adding option `-nostdin` to the invocation causes `ffmpeg` to not enable **stdin** interaction, and so avoids suspending the background process.

So, when I changed my invocation from:

```
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy path/to/dest/"$(basename -s .flac "$f")".mp3
```

to:

```
    ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$f" -c:v copy path/to/dest/"$(basename -s .flac "$f")".mp3
```

then the script ran without suspending.

You can get a similar effect by redirecting input to `/dev/null`. This can be done at the `ffmpeg` call, or at the invocation to the shell script where you send the run to the background. The nice thing about this is that you can work around `ffmpeg`'s need for **stdin** without having to modify the script which invokes `ffmpeg`. The drawback of this is that it works differently on Windows than on Linux and Mac OS X.

You would change the script invocation from:

```
% bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b &> ~/tmp/log.txt &
```

to:

```
% bin/mp3convert.sh path/a/b < /dev/null &> ~/tmp/log.txt &
```

Comment: This [answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/577055/114802) gives the same options, `-nostdin` and `</dev/null`, though to a slightly different question, _How many instances of FFmpeg commands can I run in parallel?_.

Comment: Note that none of these solutions work anymore on MacOS, at least as of 10.14.6. I have not found a solution to run ffmpeg non-interactively on that system.

Comment: @JohnSmith Interesting. Consider asking a variation on this question, but specifying macOS 10.14.6, and showing what command line you used and what symptoms you observe. I don't have 10.14 myself, but I will eventually. I will want this answer also.