# GDB suspends when it reaches breakpoint on stripped binary

Tags: gdb

I am not sure if it is a bug or I am using gdb incorrectly, but when I

1. Strip binary (remove symbols)
2. Load it under gdb
3. Put breakpoint anywhere
4. Run program reaching breakpoint

gdb gets suspended (like I would press `C-z`), which is very annoying and sometimes breaks execution. Why does it happen? I could not get any information about it, tested on different binaries on different PCs.

Example:

```
gdb-peda$ b *0x1060
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1060
gdb-peda$ r
Starting program: lab2 
[4]  + 6404 suspended (tty output)  gdb lab2

[bash ~] fg
[4]    6404 continued  gdb lab2
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x1060
```

inb4 - removing peda did not change anything

I am using `GDB 8.2` under Arch Linux 4.18 via bash or zsh

Comment: How do you put breakpoint in stripped binary? Are you setting breakpoint on memory address?

Comment: for example `b *0x690`

Comment: can you give the output of gdb when it gets suspended? what is being displayed then?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: If you put the breakpoint on a valid memory address, does it still misbehave?

Comment: Yes, I take address from peda logs on successful breaks. The strangest is that problem occurs quite randomly

Comment: Did you try in another terminal? This could be the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24056102/72178.

Comment: Tried on tty, konsole and others