# The difference between (tty output) and (tty input) error, and when do they occur?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, flask, signals

Today I try to run my [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/) server in the background (because I want to disown the job to make it detached to the running shell).

```bash
python3 server.py &
```

This command do launch the Flask server. But the process is suspended soon, emit a message:

> suspended (tty output)

And the server process CANNOT survive after the shell process exits.

After Googling for a while, I somehow know the process receive SIGTTOU or SIGTTIN. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24056296/17838999) didn't solve my problem. After redirecting the process's STDIN to /dev/null, the problem is solved.

Besides, I find if I execute

```bash
zsh -c "read hello; echo $hello" &
```

, this job is also suspended, but emit a different message:

> suspended (tty input)

That's why I'm confused. When Googling "the difference between tty input and tty output error", I couldn't find anything helpful.

Could anyone try to explain the difference between these two kinds of error, and when do they occur? Receive which signal? Who sent the signal? Why sent the signal?

Besides, I want to know why a suspended job will be killed, even if I have disowned the job?

The minimal reproducible example of my flask server:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return {"code": 200}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=10000, debug=True) # If debug is set to False, the server won't be suspended.
```